# How do you get a SwiftUI parent view to update its Core Data FetchRequest when another view saves a change to an object nested deep in parent?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

### Setup

If I have three Core Data Entities of **Outer**, **Middle** and **Inner** and they have a relationship with each other of:

**Outer** has many **Middle** which has many **Inner**

The main Context view has a @FetchRequest that pulls back all the **Outer** (so by the relationships all the **middle**s and then all their **Inner**s displaying them all like this:

[image: Main Context Page showing all 3 Entity types together]

### Problem

This works for exiting data and as soon as you add a new Outer or Middle the view updates with all the correct information even showing the correct Inner count for all previous entries. BUT if you ONLY add a new inner then the view doesn't get re-drawn and shows the old Inner Count for that Middle row.
You can add as many new Inners as you want to the existing Outer & Middle and the view won't update (unless you force close the app and re-open it).
As soon as you add a new Middle with an Inner (or Outer, Middle and Inner together) it'll update the view and correct all existing Inner Counts.

### Question

What's the correct way to tell Core Data that the view needs to know about Inner changes as well as Middle and Outer it seems to know currently?

### Replication

I've duplicated the issue with the simplest app I can. To duplicate it:

1. Create a new App with Xcode 14.3 clicking the "Use Core Data" flag
2. Change the device type to an iOS (I used: `iPhone 14 Pro Max`)
3. Replace the datamodel with the following by right clicking on the datamodel file, selecting `Show in Finder` then right clicking on the file in Finder and selecting `Show Package Contents`. Repeate for the file inside. Then open the `content` file, replacing its content with the xml below and saving it. Xcode will automaticlly pick up the change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="21754" systemVersion="22E261" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" sourceLanguage="Swift" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="">
    <entity name="Inner" representedClassName="Inner" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="category">
        <attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="started" optional="YES" attributeType="Date" usesScalarValueType="NO"/>
        <relationship name="middle" optional="YES" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="Middle" inverseName="inners" inverseEntity="Middle"/>
    </entity>
    <entity name="Middle" representedClassName="Middle" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="category">
        <attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="started" optional="YES" attributeType="Date" usesScalarValueType="NO"/>
        <relationship name="inners" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="Inner" inverseName="middle" inverseEntity="Inner"/>
        <relationship name="outer" optional="YES" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="Outer" inverseName="middles" inverseEntity="Outer"/>
    </entity>
    <entity name="Outer" representedClassName="Outer" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="category">
        <attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="started" optional="YES" attributeType="Date" usesScalarValueType="NO"/>
        <relationship name="middles" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="Middle" inverseName="outer" inverseEntity="Middle"/>
    </entity>
</model>
```

4. From the Data Model window run `Editor` - `Create NSManagedObject Subclass...`
5. Delete all the files it creates
6. Replace the Persistence.swift file with:

```
//
//  Persistence.swift
//

import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        
        newOuter(called: "One", at: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(-86400), withViewContext: viewContext)
        newOuter(called: "Two", at: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(-86400), withViewContext: viewContext)
       
        // Try to save the test data into the (in-memory) container
        shared.save()
        
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestModel")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
    
    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext
        
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Show some error here
                print("Error saving data!!")
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func newOuter(called name: String, at started: Date, withViewContext viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        // Create an Outer
        let outer = Outer(context: viewContext)
        outer.name = name
        outer.started = started
        
        // Create a Middle
        let middle1 = Middle(context: viewContext)
        middle1.name = "\(name).1"
        middle1.started = outer.started
        // Add to Outer
        outer.addToMiddles(middle1)
        
        // Create an inner
        let inner1 = Inner(context: viewContext)
        inner1.name = "\(name).1.1"
        inner1.started = middle1.started
        // Add to Middle
        middle1.addToInners(inner1)
        
        // Create an inner
        let inner2 = Inner(context: viewContext)
        inner2.name = "\(name).1.2"
        inner2.started = inner1.started?.addingTimeInterval(3600)
        // Add to Middle
        middle1.addToInners(inner2)
        
        // Create another Middle
        let middle2 = Middle(context: viewContext)
        middle2.name = "\(name).2"
        middle2.started = inner2.started?.addingTimeInterval(7200)
        // Add to Outer
        outer.addToMiddles(middle2)
        
        // Create an inner
        let inner3 = Inner(context: viewContext)
        inner3.name = "\(name).2.1"
        inner3.started = middle2.started
        // Add to Middle
        middle2.addToInners(inner3)
        
        // Create an inner
        let inner4 = Inner(context: viewContext)
        inner4.name = "\(name).2.2"
        inner4.started = inner3.started?.addingTimeInterval(3600)
        // Add to Middle
        middle2.addToInners(inner4)
        
        // Create an inner
        let inner5 = Inner(context: viewContext)
        inner5.name = "\(name).2.3"
        inner5.started = inner4.started?.addingTimeInterval(1800)
        // Add to Middle
        middle2.addToInners(inner5)
    }
}
```

7. Change the name in quotes on line 26 of `Persistence.swift` (`container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestModel")`) back to the name of your container (the file name of your data model before the `.xcdatamodelId` e.g. if your file is called `Gaz_s_Test.xcdatamodelId` it would be `Gaz_s_Test`) from `TestModel`.
8. Create a new file called: `CoreDataClass.swift` containing:

```
//
//  CoreDataClass.swift
//

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Outer)
public class Outer: NSManagedObject {
    // Wrappers to make none optional if old optional types
    var Name: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Outer!"
    }
    var Started: Date {
        (started != nil) ? started! : Date()
    }
    var Middles: [Middle] {
        let set = middles as? Set<Middle> ?? []
        
        return set.sorted {
            $0.Started < $1.Started
        }
    }
    
}

@objc(Middle)
public class Middle: NSManagedObject {
    // Wrappers to make none optional if old optional types
    var Name: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Middle!"
    }
    var Started: Date {
        (started != nil) ? started! : Date()
    }
    var Inners: [Inner] {
        let set = inners as? Set<Inner> ?? []
        
        return set.sorted {
            $0.Started < $1.Started
        }
    }
}

@objc(Inner)
public class Inner: NSManagedObject {
    // Wrappers to make none optional if old optional types
    var Name: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Inner!"
    }
    var Started: Date {
        (started != nil) ? started! : Date()
    }
}
```

5. Replace everything in `ContentView.swift` with:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

// So we can use strings as the item for the sheet...
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [
            SortDescriptor(\.started, order: .reverse)
        ]
    ) var outers: FetchedResults<Outer>
    
    @State private var selectedMiddle: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {  
                ForEach(outers, id: \.self) { outer in
                    Section(header: Text(outer.name ?? "??")) {
                        ForEach(outer.Middles, id: \.self) { middle in
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(middle.name ?? "??")")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Inner Count: \(middle.inners!.count)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Logs")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    Button {
                        selectedMiddle = "Five"
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add 5", systemImage: "5.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    Button {
                        selectedMiddle = "Four"
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add 4", systemImage: "4.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    Button {
                        selectedMiddle = "Three"
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add 3", systemImage: "3.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    Button {
                        selectedMiddle = "Two"
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add 2", systemImage: "2.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    Button {
                        selectedMiddle = "One"
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add 1", systemImage: "1.circle.fill")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedMiddle, onDismiss: {}) { selectedMiddle in
                AddView(middleName: selectedMiddle)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

6. Create a new view called `AddView.swift` and replace its content with:

```
//
//  AddView.swift
//

import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    // Optional input params
    @State var selectedOuter: Outer?
    @State var newOuterName: String = ""
    @State var middleName: String = ""
    
    // Pull back all the Outers for the dropdown
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [
            SortDescriptor(\.started, order: .reverse)
        ]
    ) var outers: FetchedResults<Outer>
    
    @State private var started = Date.now
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker ("Outer", selection: $selectedOuter) {
                        Text("New \(newOuterName) (\(Date.now.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened)))").tag(nil as Outer?)
                        ForEach(outers) { outer in
                            Text("\(outer.Name) (\(outer.Started.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened)))").tag(outer as Outer?)
                        }
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    
                    if (selectedOuter == nil) {
                        TextField("New Outer's Name (Optional will use date)", text: $newOuterName)
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    DatePicker("Started at", selection: $started, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                
                Section {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Button("Add") {
                            // Create a new Outer if none are selected
                            if (selectedOuter == nil) {
                                let newOuter = Outer(context: viewContext)
                                newOuter.started = started
                                // Add the Outer Name
                                newOuter.name = "\(newOuterName.count > 0 ? newOuterName : started.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .shortened))"
                                // Make this the selected outer
                                selectedOuter = newOuter
                            }
                            
                            // Try to find an existing middle for this middle type on this workout
                            var middle = selectedOuter!.Middles.first(where: { $0.Name == middleName })

                            // Create a new middle if one doesn't exist
                            if (middle == nil) {
                                middle = Middle(context: viewContext)
                                middle!.name = middleName
                                middle!.started = Date()
                                selectedOuter!.addToMiddles(middle!)
                            }

                            print("Before - middle has \(middle!.Inners.count) inners")

                            // Create new Inner
                            let newInner = Inner(context: viewContext)
                            newInner.started = started
                            newInner.name = "\(middleName) - \(middle!.Inners.count + 1)"
                            // Add to Middle
                            middle!.addToInners(newInner)
                            
                            print("After - middle '\(middleName)' has \(middle!.Inners.count) inners")
                            
                            // Save
                            PersistenceController.shared.save()
                            
                            // Close sheet
                            dismiss()
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button("Cancel", role: .destructive) {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    }
                }
                .listRowInsets(.init())
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            }
            .onAppear { [outers] in
                selectedOuter = outers.first(where: {$0.Started > Date.now.addingTimeInterval(-300)})
            }
            .navigationTitle(middleName)
        }
    }
}

struct AddView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

Now if you run it (Context View in the preview, Simulator or your iPhone) and click one of the numbers at the top the Add sheet will pop-up. Giving the Outer a name (or leave it for the current date) and clicking the `Add` button will add a row for the Middle with with the Outer being the Section and a count of the Inners (currently only one).
If you add a few more of that same number to the same Outer you'll see the Inner count doesn't update.
If you now add another number (Middle) that new row will show and all the Inners counts will now be correct.
You can also get the same update by force closing the app and re-opening it in the simulator or a device.

Comment: `NSManagedObject` are `ObservableObject`, `@State` isn't appropriate for seeing changes to the variables you should use `@ObservedObject` so you can see changes. `@State` and `@Binding` are for values types.

Comment: Sorry @Iorem which @State is wrong and why? I understand that the `NSManagedObject` is an Observable but I'm not storing that in an @State. I'm only passing values though to the AddView with @State as I don't expect anything back from it as I just use it to pre-fill out the Add View with defaults. I then save the new object back into the `NSManagedObject` so was expecting the Observable `NSManagedObject` being used in the `ContentView` to observe the change and update the view with the new Inner Object.

If you know the answer please post it as a filled out answer so I can learn. :)

Comment: If you don’t expect to see changes with it then you can keep it but you still haven’t wrapped everything else, every ObservableObject at every level has to be wrapped with ObservedObject to see changes to the variables. The answer is to create subviews and wrap them all.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by wrap. Swift is very new to me and I’m clearly missing something. Could you please post an answer with code explaining what I need to change to get that example app working and why @lorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more investigation over the last few hours I now think I understand what is happening and also what @Iorem was hinting at in the comments to the question.

**TLDR:** Jump to **Solution** at the bottom if you don't care about the working out and reason...

### Bad assumption

When I wrote this question I was under the assumption that SwiftUI was triggering on the update of both Outer & Middle but not Inner. This is NOT correct! It's triggering on ONLY changes to the Outer. I assumed it was changing on Middle objects as well as it updated the view when I added a new Middle

### What's actually happening

But it was actually just triggering on the new Middle that was added to the Middles array on the Outer (created by the relationship between Outer and Middle)!

### Realisation

I discovered this by added the ability to edit the Middles name while bored and playing and realised that didn't cause an update to the view and realised it was because the name change to Middle didn't change the Middles array on the Outer as therefore it clearly wasn't actually observing changes on the Middles!

Knowing now that SwiftUI is only monitoring the Outer I tried to work out how I could follow @Iorem's at the time vague suggestions (from the comments of the Question) to tell SwiftUI that I'm specifically using the Middle and Inner object as well (and which ones) by creating separate views that took in a Middle as an observable so it triggered a change to the views when they changed (not sure if there is a way of doing this without the view. Maybe some wrapper around the code instead of a new view?).

### Solution

Pulling out the SwiftUI that displays the Middle data from the `ContextView` (line 30-34):

```
HStack {
    Text("\(middle.name ?? "??")")
    Spacer()
    Text("Inner Count: \(middle.inners!.count)")
}
```

I created a new view called `MiddleRowView` with the following context:

```
//
//  MiddleRowView.swift
//

import SwiftUI

struct MiddleRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var middle: Middle
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(middle.name ?? "??")")
            Spacer()
            Text("Inner Count: \(middle.Inners.count)")
            VStack {
                ForEach(middle.Inners, id: \.self) { inner in
                    Text("Inner: \(inner.Name)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replacing the section in `ContentView` I'd pulled out with: `MiddleRowView(middle: middle)` to call that new row view passing in the `Middle` in question and as `MiddleRowView` used an `@ObservableObject` to accept the `Middle` SwiftUI now knows that I care about that specific `Middle` object and observes it.

As the example so far doesn't use any of the data inside the Inner view (name or started) so we don't actually care about changes to it but instead only the count which is got from the now observed `Middle` object's `inners` array we don't need to go any further for the count to always be correct.
**But if** we update the `MiddleRowView` to show a list of the Names of the `Inner`'s editing those names wouldn't show until you again split out that section of `MiddleRowView` into a new view that took the `Inner` as an `@ObservableObject` input like with did with the `MiddleRowView`!

Hence what @lorem was saying about "The answer is to create subviews and wrap them all"! So while it wasn't enough to count as an useful answer on it's own I do now understand what you were trying to say. Thanks @lorem!

Comment: Glad to help! It takes a minute to sink in but it always does. People ask this same question all the time, I wasn’t near my MacBook yesterday.